# JSON encode a HTML list - all childs are showed at all parents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have this ordered list:

```js
function convert( name_ref ) {
    name_ref = name_ref + " > ol > li";
    var mylist = [];
    $(name_ref).each(function () {
  if ($(this).find('> ol > li').length){
   mylist.push({
    "name": $(this).children("span").text(),
    "childs": convert( name_ref )
   });
  } else {
   mylist.push({
    "name": $(this).children("span").text()
   });
  }
    });
    return mylist;
}

function convert_final( the_list ) {
    $("#result").html(JSON.stringify(the_list));
}

convert_final( convert('.ols') );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ols">
<ol>
  <li><span>Something</span>
    <ol><li><span>Something 1</span></li></ol>
  </li>
  <li><span>Something 2</span></li>
  <li><span>Something 3</span>
    <ol><li><span>Something 4</span></li></ol>
  </li>
</ol>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

The list above has sublists like a menu with submenus. I want to encode by json the html list (to convert the list to json), but the json result is wrong because the child of "Something 3" can be found in the json at the childs of "Something" and vice-versa.

What can I do to show the olny the real child of the "li" in json.

Hope you understand my question,
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the recursive call to `convert`, `name_ref` becomes:

`.ols > ol > li > ol > li`

This picks up *all* `li` children nested two levels deep.

An alternative is to call `convert` on the jQuery collection itself:

```js
function convert(name_ref) {
  var mylist = [];

  $(name_ref).each(function () {
    var li= $(this).find('> ol > li');
    if(li.length) {
      mylist.push({
        'name': $(this).children('span').text(),
        'childs': convert(li)
      });
    }
    else {
      mylist.push({
        'name': $(this).children('span').text()
      });
    }
  });
  return mylist;
}

function convert_final( the_list ) {
  $('#result').html(JSON.stringify(the_list));
}

convert_final(convert($('.ols > ol > li')));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ols">
<ol>
  <li><span>Something</span>
    <ol><li><span>Something 1</span></li></ol>
  </li>
  <li><span>Something 2</span></li>
  <li><span>Something 3</span>
    <ol><li><span>Something 4</span></li></ol>
  </li>
</ol>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Maybe this can be of use, not tailored to your problem but same principle
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/X8J7J/